# Why isn't Luke in Bunk'd?

Tags: jessie, bunkd

In Season 1 of *Bunk'd*, a spinoff of the show *Jessie*, it is explained that Luke is at school still, studying at summer school. Apart from his one cameo, he doesn't make any appearances during seasons 2-6. Why is this? Surely he couldn't have been at summer school for **6 years**?

Comment: Is there any evidence that those six seasons span six years in-universe? Could they theoretically have taken place in the span of a single summer, like *Phineas and Ferb*?

Comment: @F1Krazy this does happen over a range of years (but perhaps not six): One summer the camp gets sold, another season begins with Bertram helping them pack. There are probably more examples though...

Comment: Most seasons happen in different summers from the other seasons, since first episode in each season usually has campers arriving at the camp, and the last episode of each season usually shows the cmap closing up at the end of the summer.  However, I have reasons to believe that the seasons are NOT set during the same summers they were on the air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most seasons happen in different summers from the other seasons, since
the first episode in each season usually has campers arriving at the camp, and the last episode of each season usually shows the camp closing up at the end of the summer.  However, I have reasons to believe that the seasons are NOT set during the same summers they were on the air.

Emma, Ravi, and Zuri buy Camp Kikiwaka at the beginning of the third season, and at the end of the third season, they each have something else to to do with their lives and sell Camp Kikiwaka to Lou at the end of the Third Season.

So Luke has a reason to visit the camp during the first, second, and third, seasons, since his adopted siblings are spending the summer there, and does appear in one episode each of the first and second seasons.  But Luke has no motive to visit Camp Kikiwaka in later seasons when Emma, Ravi, and Luke are not there.

Part Two:

For those who are interested, a note on the chronology of of *Jessie* and *Bunk'd*.

I also note that the fictional dates of *Jessie* and *Bunk'd* do not keep up with the dates the episodes were produced and broadcast by the Disney Channel, but instead lag behind.

The fourth season episode "What a Steal" (April 17, 2015) reveals that the combination of the Ross's safe is Ravi's birthdate of March 24, 2001.

https://jessie.fandom.com/wiki/What_a_Steal

In "Gotcha Day" (August 24, 2012):

> When Ravi tells the story when he first arrived in the United States, he tells Jessie that they thought Mr. Kipling was supposed to be a baby because his room was decorated like a nursery. Jessie accidentally blurts out that Morgan and Christina were probably expecting a baby instead of him. Ravi then gets incredibly upset and Christina and Morgan get mad at Jessie. The huge reveal almost ruins "Gotcha Day". Later on, Morgan and Christina tells them that his birth certificate had a typo and instead of Ravi being born in the year 2001, it said 2011, so that is why the Rosses were expecting a baby.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jessie_episodes

So Ravi must have come to the USA sometime after March 24, 2011, the date Christina and Morgan thought he was born, and probably by 2012 or 2013 if they expected a baby.  Note that Ravi turned 18 on 24 March 2019.

Ravi was adopted by the Rosses a month before "New York, New Nanny" (September 30,2011), which thus must happen in or after April 2011.

https://jessie.fandom.com/wiki/Ravi_Ross

Thus it is logical to assume that the 3rd season of *Bunk'd* would begin about 2017.  In the 2nd episode of the 3rd season of *Bunk'd, "Let's Bounce" (June 19, 2018) Emma, Ravi, and Zuri argue who should be in charge of Camp Kikiwaka.  Emma says she should be because she is 18.

So if Ravi isn't 18 yet the episode must be in the summer of 2018 or an earlier summer.  Emma was allegedly born in April 1998,

https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Emma_Ross

and so was 18 in the summer of 2016.

See also:

https://moviechat.org/tt4591680/Bunkd/5e9e0bb6ee346205ae92e507/Will-the-fifth-season-of-Bunkd-reference-the-coronavirus-pandemic

https://moviechat.org/tt4591680/Bunkd/5e97fa6b2d834940a46df9a9/Emmas-Age